# mysql stored procedure for fetching products from multiple product tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have multiple product tables (not related to each other). All products tables having some prefix like

```
computer_products
kitchen_products
..... so on
```

I have all prefix are in a separate table. I have to fetch products from all tables.

I know I can do with stored procedures but I am new to mysql queries and stored procedures. I am trying to learn but this is something urgent.

Any help for making stored procedure for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those tables can have different structures. How do you want to output them? Describe your tables, show desired result.

Comment: structure is same.  and I have to fetch values from some fix column of same names in those tables.

Comment: ...from all tables with specified prefix?

Comment: Yes same. you got this. I have to fetch prefix from a table then looping over that for fetching data from respective tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query like this -

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM computer_products
UNION
SELECT col1, col2 FROM kitchen_products
```

You can generate it using this query -

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT col1, col2 FROM ', table_name) SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
  INTO @sql
FROM
  information_schema.tables
WHERE
  table_schema = '<database name>' -- spcecify <database name>
  AND table_name LIKE '%_products';
```

This query will build SELECT query and pass it to `@sql` variable.

Then execute it using [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: How to add table_name here. That i can't to hardcode. I have table prefix in separate table. GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT col1, col2 FROM ', table_name) SEPARATOR ' UNION ')

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode here. Have a look at WHERE clause, there is what you need, I mean table prefix - `LIKE '%_products'`. This query retrieves data from MySQL metadata - table names and etc.. Set your database in WHERE clause, run that query + SELECT @sql. The variable `@sql` contains your result query. Ask questions;)